# Difference between the multilevel indexing and secondary indexing in dbms

Tags: database, indexing, rdbms

what is the exact difference between the multilevel indexing and secondary indexing in dbms as both appears same but classified different?

Answer (score 1):

Secondary Index:

The secondary Index in DBMS can be generated by a field which has a unique value for each record, and it should be a candidate key. It is also known as a non-clustering index.

Multilevel Index:

Multilevel Indexing in Database is created when a primary index does not fit in memory. In this type of indexing method, you can reduce the number of disk accesses to short any record and kept on a disk as a sequential file and create a sparse base on that file.